# How to build a functional only component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React. What I am trying to build is a component which can detect mouse status like `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousemove`, `mousedrag`, `mouse dblclick`.

This component actually has nothing with UI, so I wonder what should I return in render function? Say I have a class like:

```
class MouseActionMonitor {
    constructor(){
    }
    render(){
        return (
        )
    }
}
```

And I want to use it like( it does not have to be like this, this is just my guess of its usage):

```
ReactDOM.render( <MouseActionMonitor><App state={state} /></MouseActionMonitor>, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Here the `App` is the actually application components, `#content` is a div fill the whole window. `MouseActionMonitor` can update certain part in the `state` tree to indicate current mouse action( also still **wondering how to use this component to detect mouse action** ).

The reason I want to do this is because I want to drage and drop item between "drag/drop-able" component(this component has a text label in it, when drag it, it will give you a copy of that text, and when u hover other component of this kind, it should allow u to drop this text and replace the one current in it)

Thanks

Comment: Since React supports [These Mouse Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events) already.  Why build another container?

Comment: In this case your `MouseActionMonitor` would render the child components from `this.props.children`. `render() { return {this.props.children}; }`

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks, could you give an example how to use those to achieve what I want?

Comment: @JamieDixon Thanks, could you give an example how to actually detect those event?

Comment: @Kuan On a div, `<div onMouseEnter={handler} onMouseLeave={handler2} ... />`. Check the link @Davin posted. There is no need to have a container monitoring mouse movement as theses events are already there in React.

Comment: The thing you are talking about is called HOC or High Order Components. More read here - https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.9ojkia9og The idea is to wrap your components with logic. HOC wraps passed component with utility  functions (onclicks , etc) and returns new component.